# How do you permanently alter program data upon execution?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've written a small program which allows me to move a rectangle within a canvas widget. I plan to extend the program to allow me to move other widgets on screen so that I can move things within the window more easily, i.e moving an item via drag n drop, rather than specifying direct coords (at least not explicitly).

Here is the code so far:

from tkinter import *
    root = Tk()

```
class Move_Shape:
    data = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
    canvas = Canvas(width = root.winfo_screenwidth(), height = root.winfo_screenheight())


    def __init__(self, shape, fill = 'White', *coords):
        shape_coords = open('Shape_coords.py', 'r')
        new_coords = shape_coords.readline()[1:-1]
        new_coords = (new_coords).split(',')

        if coords != (): new_coords = coords

        if shape == 'line': 
            tag = 'line'
            self.canvas.create_line(coords, tags = tag, fill = fill)

        elif shape == 'rectangle': 
            tag = 'rect'
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(coords, tags = tag, fill = fill)
        ... More Code


        self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Button1-Motion>', self.track)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)
        self.canvas.grid()


    def click(self, event):
        self.data.update({'x': event.x, 'y': event.y})
        self.item = self.canvas.find_closest(self.data['x'], self.data['y'])

    def track(self, event):
        x, y = event.x - self.data['x'], event.y - self.data['y']
        self.canvas.move(self.item, x, y)
        self.data.update({'x': event.x, 'y': event.y})

    def release(self, event):
        self.data.update({'x': event.x, 'y': event.y})
        shape_coords = open('shape_coords.py', 'w')
        coords = str(self.canvas.coords(self.item))
        shape_coords.write(coords)
        shape_coords.close()

label = Label(text = 'text more text some more text', fg = 'white', bg = 'white')

Move_Shape('rectangle', 'blue', 50, 50, 200, 200)
Move_Shape( 'oval', 'green', 50,50,200,200)
Move_Shape( 'arc', 'red', 50,50,200,200)



mainloop()
```

So now I can move the rectangle anywhere on screen. However, when I re-open the window, the rectangle starts in it's initial position, which, albeit, was the expected outcome. The desired outcome though it to be able to keep the rectangle where it's at when it's been dropped from where it's dragged.

One such solution I can think of it writing (and rewriting) to another file, so that the new coords rewrites over the original coords within the file, though to me this seems messy, since I have to create a whole new file. Would there be a cleaner, more elegant way to achieve this, or should I go with the idea of appending the new coords to a file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The key thing you need to decide is: what is the scope of this data?

Is it:

- data that belongs to **the program itself**
- data that belongs to **the current machine**
- data that belongs to **the current user**
- something else?

It doesn't make sense to modify **the program itself** if the data belongs to, say, the current user.

Most likely, writing out the data to a file somewhere else (or, possibly, to a database) is the better solution.

Comment: Hi, it's data that belongs to the program, as in the actual file in which the data belongs too (up top). It's in the title :)

Comment: @Jim Jam I guess you just can write a config file then in the same folder. You can than copy it along with the script.

Comment: @JimJam: Sorry if my response wasn't clear. The point is, does the data actually *belong* to the program? It's important to mentally distinguish between (1) a program's source code, (2) an instance of that program installed on a particular machine, and (3) a particular execution of that program. I contend that user-modifiable data never *belongs* to #1, only #2 and #3. As such, modifying #1 (the program's source code) is incorrect because it's solving the problem at the wrong level of abstraction.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I am very grateful that you took the time to respond to my question, and though I am not clear what you mean, that's down to my lack of experience (because i've only been at this for 4 months), though I am certain to look into all the aspects of the program you have mentioned. I don't know if this clarifies things, but what I meant was that I was trying to change the variable coords, after I dragged a shape somewhere. In the end I went with the approach of writing the data to a file and then reading back the data, which seems to work. Anyway,  Thanks again for your time :)